# Saving all javascript code in an online database

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new to making an async game and I would like to know if you could just get the current gamestate and save it as it is or if I would have to grab all code seperatly and organising them into tables. It would be very useful if there was some kind of function that could save everything at once as I am building a pretty big game and it would take a long time grabbing every last piece of information.

So to summarise: I would like to grab the existing gamestate and put everything in a database, then grab everything again and restore that gamestate.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is far too broad and non-specific.  Only you as the game creator know what "game state" is.  So, you have to write code to collect the game state and send it to a database.  And, then you separately have to write code to read the game state from the database and then initialize a game with that state.  There is no generic answer to this.  It depends entirely on the way your game is written.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked this question. I was wondering if there was a way to save everything from the current state. But thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to submit (or retrieve) the gamestate data to a server with JavaScript. You can use something like JQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function for this.

For the server to do anything meaningful with your data, you'll need to use some kind of scripting language. PHP or Node.JS might be a good place to start if you're new to this.

Once the server gets the HTTP request, you can have it send a query to your database (like MySQL) and send back some kind of response.

Comment: Okay, I will do some further research on this, your comment was really helpful!